# The method isDefined(char) is undefined for the type Character

Tags: java, events, gwt, unicode, character

I'm testing to see whether an input key is a unicode character (as opposed to caps lock, insert, etc) using the Character.isDefined method in GWT.  Here is the code sample for the key event.

```
public void onKeyDown(KeyDownEvent event) {
    if (isBlank() && (Character.isDefined((char)event.getNativeKeyCode()) &&
    !event.isAnyModifierKeyDown())) {
        textBox.removeStyleName("stylename");
        textBox.setValue("");
        setBlank(false);
    }
}
```

In the "if" statement I get a runtime error "The method isDefined(char) is undefined for the type Character." There are no compiler errors, and using other static Character methods like isLetter or isDigit works fine. I also tried not casting the NativeKeyCode as a char (instead using int for the codePoint) and it still gives an error. I have found nothing on the web that even remotely explains this.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you post the stacktrace?

Comment: Does it throws NoSuchMethodException?

Comment: There isn't really a stack trace.  It does also give the errors    `[ERROR] [tablet] - Hint: Previous compiler errors may have made this type unavailable   [ERROR] [tablet] - Hint: Check the inheritance chain from your module; it may not be inheriting a required module or a module may not be adding its source path entries properly`  This happens when launching in IE9, if that helps.

Comment: try to see whats value it returns, put a breakpoint

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GWT implements only part of the java standard libraries. `isDefined` on the `Character` class is one of the method that is not implemented so you can not use it in your code. You can see how the `Character` methods are implemented [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/user/super/com/google/gwt/emul/java/lang/Character.java)

It also describes why `isDefined` isn't defined (pardon the pun ;) )

Comment: Well I can still at least use isLetterOrDigit, which covers most of the keys on the keyboard, including non-shift punctuation (for example <, >, and ? still aren't included). For the remaining ones I guess I can use exceptional cases if necessary, which involves checking the event.getNativeKeyCode() with static values from KeyCodes. I just wanted to make sure I wasn't using the method improperly. Thanks!